# Laravel cant't send request

Tags: laravel, api, rest, file, storage

I have one problem with Laravel. I try to get the download link from storage, but I can't because I have 500 error code, when I try to send a request

[image: Result request]

the token is correct.

api.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\FilesController;


Route::fallback(function () {
return abort(404);
// return view('errors.404');  // incase you want to return view
});     

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'ability:admin'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
if($request->user()->role == "user") return abort(403);
return response($request->user(), 200);
});

Route::get('/auth/test', [AuthController::class, 'test'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'ability:admin']);

Route::post('/auth/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/auth/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum','ability:admin']], function() {
Route::resource('files', FilesController::class);
});
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role' => 'admin'
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('token', [$user->role])->plainTextToken;

    $res = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ];
    return response($res, 201);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($data['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'incorrect username or password'
        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('token', [$user->role])->plainTextToken;

    $res = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ];

    return response($res, 201);
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    $response = ['message' => 'You have been successfully logged out!'];
    return response($response, 200);
}

public function test(Request $request)
{
    if($request->user()->role == "user") return response(['message' => 'user'], 200);
    if($request->user()->role == "admin") return response(['message' => 'admin'], 200);
}}
```

FilesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

class FilesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048'
    ]);


    if ($file = $request->file('file')) {
        $path = $file->store('public/files');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name2 = $file->hashName();

        // //store your file into directory and db
        // $save = new File();
        // $save->name = $file;
        // $save->store_path = $path;
        // $save->save();

        return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "File successfully uploaded",
            "file" => $file,
            "name" => $name, //oryginalna nazwa pliku
            "path" => $path, // path do pliku np. "public/files/wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf"
            "name2" => $name2 // sama nazwa pliku np. "wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf"
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 */
public function show(string $filename)
{
    // tutaj powinno być id pliku i z bazy nazwa ale jako id tutaj przekazana jest nazwa pliku z storage

    $file = new File(Storage::disk('public_files')->get($filename));
    return response()->download($file->getRealPath(), $filename);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 */
public function edit(string $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 */
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 */
public function destroy(string $id)
{
    //
}}
```

config/filesystems.php

```
'public_files' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/files'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/files',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

[image: Files structure]

I don't know why i have this error. Method store works perfectly, but method show not works. AuthController also works perfectly.

All Errors List

```
<!--
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route             [login] not defined. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\test         Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 467

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(810): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator-&gt;route(&#039;login&#039;, Array, true)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php(15): route(&#039;login&#039;)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(84): App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;redirectTo(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(69): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;unauthenticated(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;authenticate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), &#039;sanctum&#039;)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(799): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(740): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php(16): require_once(&#039;C:\\xampp\\htdocs...&#039;)
#32 {main}
-->
```

Comment: If you don't read and share the error, how can we know what the issue is?

Comment: error i show on the first image

Comment: So, do you want us to close the question as duplicate? `Route [login] not found`... are you using a package for that? I do not see `login` route on the routes you shared... basic debugging... please add more info...

Comment: Ok sorry, i edit my questions

Comment: I am assuming that if you run `php artisan route:list`, you can't see any `login` route, right? maybe with another name?

Comment: yes, i see all routes from login

Answer (score 0):

Why did the API developer go broke?
Because he didn't include the header for his `accept`-ance!

Seriously, the "route login not found" error when using an API typically occurs when the request is made without the `Accept` header set to `application/json`.

The presence of the `text/html` content-type in the error message indicates that the request was not made to an API endpoint, but rather to a regular web page.

To access a PDF file through an API, you can use the `Accept` header with a value of `application/pdf`. This will inform the server that you want to receive a file with a PDF content type as a response.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/pdf" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
  http://localhost:8000/api/files/xxxx.pdf
```

or

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
  http://localhost:8000/api/files/xxxx.pdf
```

The difference between the `Accept` header with values of `application/pdf` and `application/octet-stream` is that `application/pdf` specifically indicates that the client wants to receive a file with the PDF content type as the response, while `application/octet-stream` only indicates that the client wants to receive binary data, including files with an unknown or unspecified content type.

When accessing a PDF file through an API, it is recommended to use the `Accept` header with a value of `application/pdf`, as this specifically indicates that the client wants to receive a file with the PDF content type as the response. However, using the `Accept` header with a value of `application/octet-stream` can still be used to access a PDF file through an API, as the client can still receive the PDF file as binary data.

---

#### Update

It also appears that the issue is related to `show` method in the `FilesController`. The main problem is that you're trying to create a new `File` from the content of the file, which is not correct. Instead, you should get the path of the stored file and use it to create the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse` object.

```
public function show(string $filename)
{
    // Get the path of the stored file
    $filePath = Storage::disk('public_files')->get($filename);

    // Check if the file exists
    if (!File::exists($filePath)) {
        return abort(404, 'File not found');
    }

    // Create a BinaryFileResponse object and return it
    return response()->file($filePath, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $filename . '"'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252746/discussion-on-answer-by-wahyu-kristianto-laravel-cantt-send-request); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.